# Preventing fullscreen on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap build, but whatever I try, my app hides the status bar and default to full screen. This is odd as I'd like to use iScroll to scroll a specific child div on my main page (ie: a list of items) while keeping the main title logo visible at the top. Even without including iScroll, the whole list is scrollable anyway, out of the box. It's almost like PhoneGap build is ignoring my config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, you do not have the line `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` in your config.xml correct? If you dont have it in there it shoudld be defaulting to false but just to be sure, try adding `<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />` anyways.